# mysql error - InnoDB: file write at offset > 4 GB

Tags: mysql

currently I'm working on a large mysql-database (200mio+ rows ~40gb). Now I need to create an primary index and index some rows. But if I do so, all looks fine, but after a while the db throws tons of: [ERROR] InnoDB: file write at offset > 4 GB.

The sql querys are:

```
ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD id bigint PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE mytbl ADD INDEX (existing_row);
```

I'm using mysql 5.7.9 on Windows 10. My config looks like this:

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = 3
#GENERAL
port = 3306
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
socket = F:/mysql/mysql.sock
pid_file = F:/mysql/mysql.pid

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir = F:/mysql/data
tmpdir = F:/mysql/temp
#INNODB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
#innodb_flush_method = async_unbuffered
#MyISAM
key_buffer_size = 128M
#Logging
log_error = F:/mysql/mysql-error.log
slow_query_log = 1
slow_query_log_file = F:/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#OTHER
tmp_table_size = 32M
max_heap_table_size = 32M
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 00
max_connections = 500
thread_cache_size = 50
table_open_cache = 800
```

The filesystem of F: is NTFS.

Any suggestions?

Greetz
scotty86

Comment: [This DBA Stack exchange article](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68319/mysql-index-creation-failing-on-table-is-full) may be useful to you.

Comment: This won't work for adding a new col "id", because rows won't match when importing the dump. Also there is more then 1 TB space left for tempfiles

Comment: Couldn't fix it on windows. But with the default mysql-installation on debian I don't get this error.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @scotty86 - any news? I cant create indexes on my tables - using the same config as you do... do I simply give up on windows and switch to linux?

Comment: @ihadanny Yeah, couldn't find a windows solution, so I moved the DB to a Linux VM and everything works fine.But I could create indexes with a smaller amount of data stored in the table on windows.